# How to add a value conditional in a array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have an array of object which looks like

```
@observable setting = [
    {
      collapseHeader: SettingsSectionDisplayName.Settings,
      section: SettingsSection.Settings,
      isSelected: isLogged() ? true :  false, ==> This does not work.
    }
    
  ]
```

So,Here I have a function which is

```
isLogged = () => {
 
return //boolean on some condition
  
}
```

Now, Here How can I set the value of a key isSelected on the basis of function returned result ?

It throws an error

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: `isLogged = () {` should be `isLogged = () => {`

Comment: yes that is a typo mistake

Comment: are you using that method in a class?? otherwise try putting `const` or `var` when initializing isLogged..(And you might aswell leave `isSelected: isLogged()` if it already returns boolean)

Comment: Yes I am using a class

Comment: try `isSelected: !!isLogged()`

Comment: @ganeshk if your in a class shouldnt it be `isSelected: this.isLogged()`?

Comment: This does not work , it gives the same error

Comment: `isSelected` is resolved only once when the object is created. After that `isSelected` holds a boolean value. Can you show more code?